# Listbox scroll bar width and height problem

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, controls

I have this listbox-

```
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" MaxHeight="80" Width="Auto" Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Text}" Style="{StaticResource Textblockstyle}" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="360000000">                                       
      <ListBox.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip MaxHeight="150" MaxWidth="500" Background="LightYellow">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding listbox}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock> 
      </ToolTip>  

</ListBox.ToolTip>                                        
    </ListBox>
```

I need to set the width of the scroll bar for the list box. 
Any Ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.
I figured it out this way:

Add a scrollviewer to the listbox and define resources for it.

8
8

Comment: <ScrollViewer.Resources>
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">8</sys:Double>
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">8</sys:Double>
</ScrollViewer.Resources>

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this.  The best way is to write a custom style for your ListBox in which you explicitly set the width of the scrollbar.  You can use [StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/) to get the current style, then copy and paste it into your Xaml and modify it as desired.

The next best way is to hack into the template itself.  In the default ListBox template there isn't a named part for the scrollbars, and in fact it uses a ScrollViewer.  But you could write a custom style with control template just for a ScrollViewer, and add it to the ListBox resources so that you set it up for your ListBox.

You could also drill down into the visual tree and set the scrollbars directly.  Use something like [Peter Blois' Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see what's in a specific visual tree.

Comment: Thanks for the answ. I figured this out this way:

Comment: @WhoCares: I think your comment got clipped.

Comment: sorry about that.. I added a comment in the end.